# Service and IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, service, intentservice, multiple-choice

If a Service is created as a subclass of IntentService base class which of the following statement is accurate?

- Service runs in the context of the main thread of the application owning the Service
- Service runs as a worker thread in the application owning the application
- Service runs in the context of the invoking application

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming none of these option are correct as IntentService is not a standalone class by itself and requires Service base class!?.. Not sure if my assumption is correct.

Comment: If you want to add more info to the question, then edit that question. Don't create a new answer that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Hi Jhanzaib, I am a beginner at stack overflow so might have misunderstood what I feel should be an answer, or an extension of my question. However, if you could help I'll be glad!